# Saving and reading three models in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model, save, has-and-belongs-to-many

I was working around join three models. I have Hospital, Doctor and Specialty. A **Hospital** hasAndBelongsToMany **Doctor** and a **Doctor** hasAndBelongsToMany **Specialty**. So 1 doctor could work in 1 Hospital with 1 specialty, but the same doctor could work in another hospital with another specialty.

I need to create a table in the database joinning 3 models like this:

table: doctors_hospitals_specialties
fields:  id  |   doctor_id    |  hospital_id   |   specialty_id

but it is not working for me. I have searched in a lot of forums the way to implement this but I couldn't find anything. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a `DoctorsHospitalsSpecialties` model.

```
Doctor hasMany DoctorsHospitalsSpecialties
Hospital hasMany DoctorsHospitalsSpecialties
Specialty hasMany DoctorsHospitalsSpecialties

DoctorsHospitalsSpecialties belongsTo Doctor, Hospital, Speciality.
```

You probably have to write some code by yourself to manage the the data in the DoctorsHospitalsSpecialties model.